# Animate viewWillAppear and viewWillDisappear?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uikit

If I do not use any helper controllers like UINavigationController, is there a way to animate the removal and adding of a controller's view, for instance when setting the detail controller of a split view? I tried to use anImation in viewWillDisappear without success. What is the correct approach?
Does the one who removes the old view and adds the new view have to take care of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, if you have to put the animation code in the "parent" object (the object that add/remove the view) maybe using [UIView animateWithDuration:...] not in the view itself

Comment: And what would be the way to do it wrt UISplitViewController? I can only set a new controller to the array of view controllers.

Comment: I'm not sure it apply to all the different kind of controllers, but if you use Storyboards you can have custom effects on Segues: maybe this can help you

Comment: No, I don't have storyboards.